# EntityFramework Code First 1 to 1 data add

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm creating a database using the code-first way.
I have two entities in a 1 to 1 relation, but I don't really know how to instantiate them.

Assume those are my entities:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("BigFoo")]
    public int BigFooId {get;set;}
    public virtual BigFoo BigFoo {get;set;}
}

public class BigFoo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId{get;set;}
    public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

This is my code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo = db.Foo.Add(foo);

BigFoo big = new BigFoo {Foo = foo, FooId = foo.Id};
big = db.BigFoo.Add(big);

//HERE is my doubt
//I don't know if I have to add the relation also in the Foo object
//Do i need the following code?

//foo.BigFoo = big;
//foo.BigFooId = big.Id;
//db.Foo.Attach(foo);
//var entry = db.Entry(foo);
//entry.Property(x => x.BigFoo).IsModified = true;

db.SaveChanges();
```

The relation is already set in my BigFoo object declaration, do I need anyway to set this relation also in the Foo object or it will be automatically assigned?

Thanks all for the help.

EDIT:

I have another doubt: I have my foreign keys named relatedentityIdField.

I have to istantiate also them with the

```
foo.BigFooId = big.Id;
```

Or those relations are automatically filled?

**ADD EXAMPLE-EDIT**

An example can be the relation *Nation* - *President*

Every Nation has only one president, and every president is only the president of a Nation.

How can I set this relation using Code-First?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current model what you really have is two one to many unidirectional relationships. To create a one to one relationship using Code First you must define the PK of the dependent entity as FK of the relationship too (check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html) for a detailed explanation).

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id{get;set;}

  public virtual Boo Boo {get;set;}
}

public class Boo
{
  [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
  public int FooId{get;set;}

  public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
}
```

With this model, you could add data as follows:

1. If you want to create a new `Foo` and `Boo` and you want to relate them, you can do the following:

   ```
   var boo=new Boo();
   var foo=new Foo{Boo=boo };
   context.Foos.Add(foo);
   context.SaveChanges();
   ```

You should see `Foo` navigation property in your `Boo` entity is also filled.

2. If `Foo` already exist and you want to create a new `Boo` related with that foo:

   You can set the `Boo` navigation property in your foo entity:

   ```
   var foo= context.Find(yourId);
   foo.Boo=new Boo();
   context.SaveChanges();
   ```

   Or you can just set the PK/FK property of your new `Boo` entity:

   ```
    var fooId=1;// You already have the Foo id
    var boo = new Boo() { FooId = fooId};
    context.Boos.Add(boo);
    context.SaveChanges();
   ```

Whit your model, as I said before, you have two different relationships, so your navigation properties aren't really related. If you want to prove that, add two collections to your entities:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("BigFoo")]
    public int? BigFooId {get;set;}
    public virtual BigFoo BigFoo {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<BigFoo> BigFoo{get;set;}// Add this property
}

public class BigFoo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int? FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos{get;set;}// Add this property
}
```

And later try this:

```
using (var context=new MyContext())
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    context.Foos.Add(foo);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var boo = new BigFoo() { FooId = foo.Id};

    context.Boos.Add(boo);
    context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

After the last `SaveChanges` you will  `Foo` nav. property in `boo` instance and `BigFoos` nav property in `foo` instance are properly filled.

**Notes:** I changed your navigation properties to `virtual` to meet one of the requirements of [Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx), and I also changed your FK properties as nullables to avoid cycles of cascading delete. Code First did not setup a cascade delete for the optional relationships.

Comment: EDIT ON COMMENT: on a second reading of the link you posted I understood the PK-FK motivation. I just don't understand what I need to set to make the relation works. I only need the PK-FK of the dependant object or I need also the objects in the two entities? Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. What is mandatory is declare at least one navigation property in one of the entities related. That is enough to EF to know there is a relationship, but in the case of one to one like I show above, you have to declare a PK in dependent entity, which is use a FK too, so, there is not many options here. But in case for example of one to many, you can omit the FK property, EF will handle for you.